# Installing Software inside Docker Windows Container

Tags: .net, docker, powershell, command-line, windows-container

I'm trying to make an image with a windows container with some pre-installed programs that my .NET app needs in order to work.

I copied all the EXE files into the container successfully but was unable to install them using the CMD as a shell or Powershell as a shell with the `Start-Process` command.

When I'm running these commands within the container it outputs nothing, and when I'm running it using the `RUN` command inside the Dockerfile in just hang on the command.

There's any way to install EXE programs on a windows container?

Edit:
My Dockerfile contains:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Start-Process should work in your container.

For reference, here is a working Dockerfile for installing Java 11 into a Windows container:

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/windows/servercore:ltsc2019-amd64

ARG src="jdk-11.0.16_windows-x64_bin.exe"
ARG target="C:/"
COPY ${src} ${target}

RUN powershell Start-Process -filepath 'C:/jdk-11.0.16_windows-x64_bin.exe' -Wait -PassThru -ArgumentList "/s"

ENV JAVA_HOME "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-11.0.16"
```

Here are a few changes to try:

- For your case, place your `/qn` argument after the -ArgumentList flag. The final RUN statement should look more like this -

```
RUN powershell ; \
 $ErrorActionPreference = 'Stop' ; \
 $ProgressPreference = 'SilentlyContinue' ; \
 Start-Process -filepath './bin/Basler_pylon_6.2.0.21487.exe' -Wait -PassThru -ArgumentList "/qn"
```

- The `USER ContainerAdministrator` statement is not needed. That is already the Docker default.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the comment above, I have a things:

- The Windows image you're using is not supported anymore. I recommend you try the Server Core image or the Server image. The latter is only supported on Windows Server 2022 nodes (or Windows 11).
- I noticed your screenshot looks like a Mac. Are you running on a Mac or is that just the screenshot? Windows containers require a Windows host to run.
- Can you run a container interactively to try and run the command? You can try `docker run -it --entrypoint mcr.microsoft.com/windows/servercore:ltsc2022` (or `ltsc2019` on a Windows Server 2019/Windows 10)